# Apache Netbeans IDE remote synchronization window says "file must be merged"

Tags: ftp, sync, netbeans, ide, remote-connection

I've got a PHP project in Netbeand IDE.
The IDE is connected over FTP to a web server, and I don't use any source control.
So, I just write code on a PC, and after a while I synchronize it to the server via FTP.
Normally, this is always working.
In some cases when there are changes on the server, I accept the synchronization of that files too, so that changes will be downloaded from the server then.

Now I installed a composer package via SSH (using PuTTY). This means of course files have been changed and added on the server. So, I click *Synchronize...* in Netbeans IDE.
Now I get errors in the synchronization window, below is an image:

[image]

Actually, all errors are of the same kind: "File must be merged before synchronization.".
I don't know what to do and I don't understand the error. I can't find any help on the internet.

Comment: Why have you got both download and upload checked?

Comment: I always do that, because I want to upload my changes I made locally, and at the same time I want to download the possible changes from the server.